# Create 20000 caseComments after inserting a new Case

Tags: triggers, salesforce, backend, apex

New to salesforce and Apex, i got a home task which im asked to create 20000 caseComments on a Case after insert. caseComments and Case are different objects but they are associated. i thought its going to be simple but the problems starts when reaching the DML limits of 10k per transaction.

I Tried to change the Inner and outer loops in my batch but nothing works, I'm able to create 9800 new CaseComments and if i cannot increase the Loop values even by 1 cause it will pass the limit.

The Trigger:

```java
trigger CommentsOnCaseInsert on Case (after insert) {
    System.debug('Triggered');
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.new.size() == 1) {
        CreateCaseCommentsBatch batch = new CreateCaseCommentsBatch(Trigger.new[0].Id);
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        
    }
}
```

The Batch job :

```java
public class CreateCaseCommentsBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    private Id caseId;
    public CreateCaseCommentsBatch(Id caseId) {
        this.caseId = caseId;
    }
   
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId]);
    }
    // Execute method to create case comments
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Case> scope) {
        List<CaseComment> caseCommentsToInsert = new List<CaseComment>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 150; i++) { 
            for (Integer j = 0; j < 66; j++) {
                 Integer commentNumber = i * 66 + j + 1;
                CaseComment caseComment = new CaseComment(
                    ParentId = caseId,
                    CommentBody = 'Dummy Comment ' + commentNumber + ' - Of Case: ' + caseId
                );
                caseCommentsToInsert.add(caseComment);
            }
            insert caseCommentsToInsert;
            caseCommentsToInsert.clear();
        }
    }
    // Finish method `your text`
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have won't work because your batch job is still going to call `execute()` only once. It'll be detached context from the main case trigger, with fresh set of limits - but still, just one. So same 10K DMLs applies.

You could cheat by inserting 6666 in `start()`, `execute()` and `finish()`. Bit weak, stretching the solution but hey.

You could look into daisy-chaining the batches (call `Database.executeBatch()` inside `finish()`). If you'd pair it with some counter variable passed like 5K done, do next chunk it could work fairly well. Maybe read up about `Database.Stateful` if you think you need such counter.

Another option is `Queueable`, good for similar "are we there yet" work.

Last but not least, there's option to call a batch with "Iterable" (`start()` method returns a list of things that doesn't have to come from database, can be created completely in memory... That'd be nice as in it'd call multiple execute()s 200 at a time or whatever... But I don't know how your memory usage would be if you were to create 20K case comments in memory and degrade executes to just inserting them.

Comment: Perfect response sir, Thank you. solved it with the Last but not least approach , made the most sense for me.